# Why do I keep getting a different result then the tutorial I am following?

Tags: css, containers, padding

I can not get the padding to register for the . I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YFrGy_mzjY and I keep running into problems he does not seem to be facing.

Here's html code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Portfolio Website - The Other Side</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="container">
            <nav>
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Here's style.css code:

```
*{margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
box-sizing: border-box;}

body {background:   #010203;
    color: #fff;}

#header {width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(images/faces\(black\).jpg);
    background-size: 55% 900px;
    background-position: 600px 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
img { width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
     }

.container {padding: 10px 10%;}`
```

I was expecting the logo and the home, about, etc pages to all go more to the right. I tried doing maybe 20pc 20% instead of 10, but nothing changed. I was hoping maybe I just forgot to close a tag or something, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your "container" element has id, not class, so css selector should be `#container`, not `.container`

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you Nikita! Have no idea why he is not running into the same problems.